Picamera2 ModuleNotFoundError
I was recently trying to use the picamera2 library for a python project but when I try to run the program it shows the following error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/litrobo/Desktop/litdet/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from picamera2 import Picamera2, Preview
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'picamera2'

I tried installing picamera2 again and it showed
sudo apt install -y python3-picamera2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-picamera2 is already the newest version (0.3.17-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

The program was run inside a virtual environment. Could this be a problem with wrongly naming the module, my program was an example program from the picamera2 library documentation.
from picamera2 import Picamera2, Preview
import time
picam2 = Picamera2()
camera_config = picam2.create_preview_configuration()
picam2.configure(camera_config)
picam2.start_preview(Preview.QTGL)
picam2.start()
time.sleep(2)
picam2.capture_file("test.jpg")


If you use sudo apt install python3-picamera2 you are installing picamera2 in the global env.  It won't be accessible by default in any virtual env you create before or afterwards.  You can install picamera2 or any other package in your venv without installing globally.
sudo apt -y install python3-venv python3-pip # should be preinstalled tho
cd /path/to/project                          # navigate to venv home
python3 -m venv my_venv                      # create a venv
source my_venv/bin/activate                  # activate venv 
pip install picamera2                        # install picamera2 

run your script.  in my_venv terminal prompt looks like (my_venv)pi@raspberrypi:~$
close my_env with deactivate.  terminal prompt returns to pi@raspberrypi:~$
